# ParametricPlot3D[] Question

Tags: graphics3d, parametric-functions

I know this is very similar to a previous question I asked, but there are some differences.  When I graph:

```
 ParametricPlot3D[
 If[Part[RotationMatrix[-ArcCos[7/Sqrt[83]], {-5, 3, 0}] . {9*Cos[s]*
 Sin[(Pi/7) t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[(Pi/7) t], 
 11*Cos[(Pi/7) t]}, 3] < 21/Sqrt[83], 
 RotationMatrix[-ArcCos[7/Sqrt[83]], {-5, 3, 0}] . {9*Cos[s]*
 Sin[(Pi/7) t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[(Pi/7) t], 
 11*Cos[(Pi/7) t]}, {7*(Cos[s]) (7 - t)/7 + 5, 
 4*(Sin[s]) (7 - t)/7 + 5, t + 5}], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, (7/Pi)*Pi}]
```

I get:

[image]

But  I want to get a clean combination of:

```
  ParametricPlot3D[
  If[Part[RotationMatrix[-ArcCos[7/Sqrt[83]], {-5, 3, 0}] . {9*Cos[s]*
  Sin[(Pi/7) t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[(Pi/7) t], 
  11*Cos[(Pi/7) t]}, 3] < 21/Sqrt[83], 
  RotationMatrix[-ArcCos[7/Sqrt[83]], {-5, 3, 0}] . {9*Cos[s]*
  Sin[(Pi/7) t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[(Pi/7) t], 
  11*Cos[(Pi/7) t]}], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, (7/Pi)*Pi}]
```

[image] (this picture should not have a scratchy top, I don't why it does, please help) and:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{7*(Cos[s]) (7 - t)/7 + 5, 4*(Sin[s]) (7 - t)/7 + 5, 
t + 5}, {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, (7/Pi)*Pi}]
```

[image]

When I say combination, I want to be able to have an equation that represents the combination of both graphs which is able to manipulated (rotated, shifted,etc...).  If I combine them using Show[] this is quite difficult, because Show[], is not an actual math equation that is manipulable. I especially want to be able to apply RotationMatrix[] to the resulting combination equation.

Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very good reason for Mathematica to display a weird plot: your surfaces aren't connected:

```
r[s_, t_] := 
  Part[RotationMatrix[-ArcCos[7/Sqrt[83]], {-5, 3, 0}].{9*Cos[s]*
      Sin[(Pi/7) t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[(Pi/7) t], 11*Cos[(Pi/7) t]}, 3];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{9*Cos[s]*Sin[(Pi/7) t], 10*Sin[s]*Sin[(Pi/7) t], 11*Cos[(Pi/7) t]}, 
                   {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, (7/Pi)*Pi},
                   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, s, t}, r[s, t] < 21/Sqrt[83]]],
  ParametricPlot3D[{7*(Cos[s]) (7 - t)/7 + 5, 4*(Sin[s]) (7 - t)/7 + 5, t + 5},
                   {s, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, (7/Pi)*Pi},
                   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, s, t}, r[s, t] > 21/Sqrt[83]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You should work out the math.

Comment: Why does the fact that my surfaces are disconnected, make it weird for Mathematica to graph?

Comment: @user9197 Because Mma tries to connect them ...

Comment: Oh. Is there anyway to not use Show[] and implicitly graph the two surfaces without having Mathematica connected them?

Comment: @user9197 Yes, but ... why don't you want to use `Show[]`? It is the natural way ...

Comment: Because after I graph ^^ I want to take the whole graph and apply a rotation to it.. and this is hard to do when I use show..In other words I want also be able to mathematically represent this rotation.

Comment: @user9197 So please edit your question and write down the whole story.

Comment: @user9197 No need to complicate the question. `Rotate[#, Pi, {1, 0, 0}] &@First@show // Graphics3D`. Where `show = Show[g1,g2]`